# How to switch boolean on button click through MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, button, boolean

I'm busy with an experiment. I'm trying to echo 10 buttons, each button is adressed to an id and a booolean (2 rows in phpmyadmin). I want each button to, if pressed, invert in color by means of the boolean value. (if true, button becomes black, if false, button is white). On top of this, I want an ajax Htmlrequest so that you can see the changes in real time.

I want the echoed out buttons to invert color by means of a function on the click of the button. This should go through an xml httprequest that gets the data from the database.

*** Edits ***

I'm trying to be more precise in my question 
I worked on the code, it still doesn't work, but i feel like it's getting close.

---

logs.php

```
 $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","test","") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL!");
 mysqli_select_db($con, "buttons") or die ("Database not found!");

 $result1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM buttons ORDER by id DESC");

 while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
 {
     if($extract['bool'] = true){
        echo "<form name='form1' mehod='POST'>
  <input type='button' name='btn' class='$id' href='#' style='background-color:black;' onclick='submitbtn()'/><br />
  </form>
        ";
    } else{
        echo "<form name='form1' mehod='POST'>
  <input type='button' name='btn' class='$id' href='#' style='background-color:white;' onclick='submitbtn()'/><br />
  </form>
        ";

    }

 }
?>
```

insert.php

```
 $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","test","") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL!");
 mysqli_select_db($con, "buttons") or die ("Database not found!");

  $btn = $_REQUEST['btn'];
 $btn = !$btn;

 $con->query("INSERT INTO logs (`bool`) VALUES ($btn)");
 $result1 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
    ?>
```

Index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Broahah</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

    <script>
  function submitbtn() {

   form1.btn = true;
   var btn = form1.btn.value;
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpsRequest();

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
     var logs = document.getElementById("logs");
     logs.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }

   xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?btn='+btn, true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }

  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    setInterval(function() {$('#logs').load('logs.php');}, 200);
  });
 </script>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="logs">
   loading...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Hey, welcome here. I see it is your first question, it is a good start but the question looks too broad. I would be great if you could ask more detail question or what exactly part of the code you are struggling with?

Comment: hi @DmytroHuz Thanks for your advice, i  edited the question and I hope it's more clear now.